# Setting CPU and Memory limits globally for all docker containers

Tags: docker, memory, cpu

There are many examples which talks about setting memory, cpu etc using docker run. Is it possible to set it globally so every container created with those values?

Answer (score 0):

There should be other ways like using AppArmor maybe, I'll check, but the first thing that comes to my mind is this project from a friend

Docker enforcer
https://github.com/piontec/docker-enforcer

This project is a docker plugin that will kill containers if they don't meet certain pre-defined policies such as having strict memory and cpu limits

Comment: Little confused. There are no configs we can do daemon.json or somewhere else to achieve what I am asking